# Email Blast - Adding an .ics ( Calendar Event ) to an anchor tag and having it open within Outlook

Tags: html, outlook

**[Link to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Kyn2g/2/)**

My first attempt at an HTML email blast and I'm kind of stuck on attaching an .ics and having it open within outlook or whatever their preferred email client is instead of downloading the .ics file directly.

The requirement
 1. Clicking on the image adds an event to your calendar. (I prefer this not to be a hosted .ics file, but my searching has not led me to a way to hardcode the .ics within the HTML email)

Here's the offending HTML:

```
<a href="webcal://http://mathiasprovinggrounds.com/WinterWunderman/WundermanWinterParty.ics"><img class="image_fix" src="http://i.imgur.com/SvlJYLU.jpg" alt="Wunderman Winter Party!" title="We Survived the Holidays! Until next year..." width="x" height="x" /><a href="">
```

Currently when the email is sent and the user clicks on the image, the calendar is downloaded via their preferred web browser and not opened directly in outlook.

I've tried the following:

1. Hosting the .ical directly and using href="http://mathiasprovinggrounds.com/WinterWunderman/WundermanWinterParty.ics"
2. Using the webcal attribute as found **[here](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar-authoring#Add_subscribe_to_events_link)**.

Is there a specific way I could hard code an .ics instead of hosting it on my server? That seems to be the ideal solution, but the only results I have found would include PHP and I would like to keep everything within a single HTML.

Comment: Editing the Header to <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/calendar; charset=utf-8" /> and updating the href to webcal://http://mathiasprovinggrounds.com/WinterWunderman/WundermanWinterParty.ics opens the .ics within mac calendar program rather than outlook. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you were looking for could be found on this page under **Creating a single-event link**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846807.aspx

Your URL, with the values replaced:

```
http://calendar.live.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?rru=addevent&dtstart=START_DATE_AND_TIME&dtend=END_DATE_AND_TIME&summary=EVENT_TITLE&location=LOCATION_TEXT
```

**START_DATE_AND_TIME** = yyyymmddThhmmss, required.

**END_DATE_AND_TIME** = yyyymmddThhmmss, required.

**EVENT_TITLE** = Escaped string, optional.

**LOCATION_TEXT** = Escaped string, optional.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- I'm unable to validate if this solves the problem as described above as I don't have any of my source files from that time.

But have an upvote -- I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks! i forgot to mention, that in order to get the correct AM/PM you have to use 24-hour format. (Goof in MS's documentation.)  yyyymmddThhmmss becomes yyyymmddTHmmss